# Theory of Turing machine which outputs Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models

I understand the notion of [the universal Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) ($U$), which receives a pair of Turing machine ($M$) and an input to $M$ ($x$). If $M$, which obtains $x$, outputs $y$, $U$, which obtains $(M, x)$, outputs $y$ as follows:

$M: x \mapsto y \\
U: (M, x) \mapsto y$

My question is whether there is a theory of another type of Turing machine where the output (not input) of Turing machine is another Turing machine like:

$U': x' \mapsto M$

I guess a program which generates another program can be regarded as this kind of Turing machine $U'$. If so, automatic code generator and machine learning algorithm might be regarded as this type of Turing machine.

(Maybe, brains of human programmers can be modeled using a theory of such Turing machines because a source code seems a form of Turing machine.)

Comment: Like, every functional programming language? I'm confused by this question. You seem to accept that Turing machines can be represented as numbers (you should really write $\langle M \rangle$ as input), numbers can be the ouput of a TM, so: yea, of course that's possible! In the standard theory.

Comment: @Raphael Of course, I understand Turing machine can output another Turing machine. My concern is whether there is a (interesting) theory about such Turing machine.  Turing machines receiving (<M>, x) can be the Universal Turing machine, which has very interesting properties. I'd like to know whether there is interesting theory about Turing machine providing another Turing machine. I guess machine learning or automatic coding are candidates.

Comment: I'm afraid that's way too broad then: there are many, many instances of such behaviour. Community votes, please!

Comment: @rkjt50r983 Yes, recursion theory, or computation theory studies this in details.  See, for an example, the [$s_{mn}$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smn_theorem) for a starter.

Comment: Have you tried to make any such interesting machines outputing machines by yourself?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think algorithms used in machine learning techniques are interesting examples, which includes the back propagation algorithm. These algorithms generate new input and output relationships extracted from training data.

Comment: @rkjt50r983: I don't know of anyone who actually programmed machine learning algorithms with Turing machines. You could ask the same question at the level of programming languages, and that might lead you to [meta-programming(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming). That's an actually useful activity.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what your are referring as "theory" (which basically means everything or anything).

Something which is closely related to what you are referring can be the 
field of **Program transformations**, which tries to study systematically 
programs that modifies other programs. The original interest of this field is the transformers that are semantically invariants (with a bit of hand waving:  you want to study transformers $T$ such that for any program (or a TM) $p$, $T(p)$ *does the same thing* as $p$). Derives from these original considerations the subfield of **program synthesis** (here, given some input datas, you want to automatically generate a program that satisfies some conditions encoded by you input).

A good introduction can be the thesis of M. Ward *"Proving Program Refinements and Transformations"* with an emphasis on the proof of program side.